# Должны ли работать WinForms Design time классы под Net5 в VS 16.8.0?

Tags: c#, winforms, design, .net

Установил VS 16.8.0 с новой Net5.
Они вроде как пишут что WinForms в этой версии Net5 должен полностью поддерживаться.

Пробую перевести свои компоненты под Net5.
Создал новые проекты под WinForms.
Установил

- Target framework .NET 5.0
- Output type: Class Library

Проекты скомпилились без ошибок.
Но в тестовых проектах в design-time при клике мышкой на мой контрол, который находится на форме, контрол не выбирается.
Стандартные выбираются нормально.

По ощущениям не срабатывает строка для DesignerAttribute

```
[Designer("EhLib.WinForms.Design.DataGridDesigner, EhLib.WinForms.Design")]
public class DataGridEh : DataAxisGrid
{...
```

В библиотеках под Net framework 4.7 все проекты работают корректно.

Comment: Там же новый Winforms дизайнер, может дело в этом? [Не оно случаем](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25058866/12888024)?

Comment: По вашей ссылке вопрос (DesignerAttribute usage) описывает проблему при использовании GAC. Я пока использую без установки в GAC. Просто добавляю в проект ссылку на сборки RunTime и DeisgnTime.